# How to persist state between tabs (TabBar) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, state-management

I have a `TabBarView` with 3 `TabBar`. When I'm in tab 1 I do something, then I navigate to tab 2 when I come back to tab 1 I want to the previous state of tab 1 will not change.

How can I achieve this in Flutter?

Below is my code screenshot

```
class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  PageController pageController;
  TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = pageController.page.floor();
        });
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
              bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
              onTap: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndex = index;
                  tabController.animateTo(index,
                      duration: Duration(microseconds: 300),
                      curve: Curves.bounceIn);
                });
              },
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.assignment), title: Text("Các yêu cầu")),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.history), title: Text("Lịch sử")),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text("Hồ sơ")),
              ]),
          body: TabBarView(
              controller: tabController,
              children: [
                RequestPage(key: PageStorageKey<String>("request_page"),),
                HistoryPage(key: PageStorageKey<String>("history_page")),
                ProfilePage(key: PageStorageKey<String>("profile_page"))])
          ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the code snippet

Comment: I added my code screenshot. Please give me some advice.

Comment: do not share code in form of screenshots please, and please do share the code of your pages and the code in the screenshot but as text so we may help more efficientlly.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Make sure that all of your `TabBarView` children are `StatefulWidgets` and then add a [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html) like so in all of them, for example, for your `RequestPage`, it should look like this:

```
class RequestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  RequestPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RequestPageState createState() => _RequestPageState();
}

class _RequestPageState extends State<RequestPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return // Your widget tree
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Is any drawback with this approach?

Comment: No, it's actually one of the most correct ways to do so, that's exactly for that the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` exists. However, have in mind that `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` will only work under keepAlive notifiers, such as `TabBarView`, `ListView` and a few more. Those are the parent widgets that iterate over its children and "ask" whether they should keep alive or recycled. If you use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` without any of those parents, it won't have any effect.

Comment: Best answer! Followed instructions and worked like a charm! Make all TabBarView children **Stateful**, conform all children to **AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin** , override **wantKeepAlive** in all children, and  called **super.build(context)** inside the build method of all the children.

Comment: Can we use. provider consumer to still initiate updates within the tabs if using this?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't have any impact.

Answer (score 2):

As the body of `Scaffold` Use `IndexedStack` to preserve state. Example :

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                ...
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                ...
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: IndexedStack(
            children: <Widget>[
              PageOne(),
              PageTwo(),
            ],
            index: _selectedIndex,
          ),
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html) and override wantKeepAlive to always return true