# StreamBuilder stuck in connectionState.waiting in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a todo list application, i used `Streambuilder` to show list of Streams.
it is a simple application there is a button to add new task it is a `floatingActionButton` and a `StreamController` to manage the data, and have a `TabBar` with two tabs **first** and **second** so the `StreamBuilder` is in the first tab and other tab just contain a string in the center for now.

I can add tasks to the StreamController perfectly, but there is two issues:

1- when the program runs `StreamBuilder` stuck in `ConnectionSatate.waiting` if the Stream is null.

2- when i click **second** tab and came back to **first** tab the it also stuck in `ConnectionSatate.waiting` even my stream has data in it, and when i click add button to add new data it shows the data and the new one again.

here is my whole code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final StreamController<List<String>> streamController =
      StreamController<List<String>>.broadcast();

  List<String> list = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  int i = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
            child: Container(
              height: 30,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: TabBar(
                  labelColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                  indicatorColor: Colors.green.shade600,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'first'),
                    Tab(text: 'second'),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(children: [
          tasks(),
          Center(
            child: Text('SECOND TAB'),
          )
        ]),
        floatingActionButton: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              list.add('data ${++i}');
              streamController.sink.add(list);
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  Padding tasks() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13, vertical: 5),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                  stream: streamController.stream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: Text('There is no data'),
                      );
                    }
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                snapshot.data![index],
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ));
                  })),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[here is a video of my problem](https://www.kapwing.com/videos/6366371871f3970235be1bc7)

> I tried without `StreamController` but when i came back to **first** tab it shows the error that i can't listen to a Stream multiple times.

Comment: what do you see on the log if you `print(snapshot)`?

Comment: @pskink it stuck on loading state until it gets data

Comment: If I skip broadcast, it can work fine with initial list

Comment: @pskink   it prints this: AsyncSnapshot<List<UserChats>?>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null)

Comment: and what does it print if you call `streamController.sink.add(list)`?

Comment: @pskink `StreamController<List<String>>()..sink.add([])` works as expected

Comment: @pskink. it will print this: AsyncSnapshot<List<String>>(ConnectionState.active, [data 1, data 2, data 3, data 4, data 5, data 6, data 7], null, null)

Comment: so why do you say it's only `ConnectionSatate.waiting`?

Comment: @pskink  i didn't say when i click the add button.  I said when i click the second tab and then came back to the first tab it will stuck in waiting state

Comment: ah, sorry, I missed that

Comment: @pskink  it's ok dude

Answer (score 0):

here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383732/how-to-persist-state-between-tabs-tabbar-in-flutter), you need to use [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html)
I wrote a demo code sample for you https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=52e8e2ef8bad97f21dc91fa420dcec0e

Answer (score 0):

Use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`. Create a dart file named `keep_alive_wrapper.dart` and put the below code:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class KeepAliveWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const KeepAliveWrapper({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  KeepAliveWrapperState createState() => KeepAliveWrapperState();
}

class KeepAliveWrapperState extends State<KeepAliveWrapper>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return widget.child;
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Wrap your widget with `KeepAliveWrapper`, here is how:

```
........... 
body: TabBarView(children: [
      KeepAliveWrappper(child:tasks()),
      Center(
        child: Text('SECOND TAB'),
      )
    ]),
    ........
```

This will solve this problem